# Number of different magmas up to isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, binary-operations, magma

Let $(M,\circ)$ be a magma over a finite set of order $n$. I tried to count all the possible magmas up to isomorphism, but I just can't get it right. My naive approach was to count all the possible Cayley tables, that is $n^{n^2}$ and trying to divide this figure by something. Now, what is this something? I guess it's related to $n!$ but my imagination stops here.

EDIT: I think, but might well be wrong, that the two following problems are equivalent restatements of the original problem.

*graph-theoretical flavor:* enumerate up to isomorphism all the bipartite graphs on the sets $A$ and $B$ such that $|A|=n^2$ and $|B|=n$ and every vertex in $A$ has degree one.

*"ball-boxing" flavor:* enumerate in how many ways one can distribute $n^2$ identical balls in $n$ identical boxes.

Comment: This may be tricky to enumerate. Using the *Magma* Maple package gives that the sequence starts $1, 1, 10, 3330, 178981952, \ldots$; the last of these has factorization $2^6\cdot 23 \cdot 121591$, which suggests more than just ratios of powers and factorials are involved.

Comment: I see. I just wonder what mysterious hidden machinery makes many of these counting procedures so cumbersome and complicated...

Comment: I think it's that the size of the isomorphism class depends very sensitively on the multiplication table. (It's not necessarily the case here, but) sometimes enumeration is just hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (very complicated) formula computing the number of isomorphism classes of magmas of a given, finite order appears in [this article](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1966-017-03/S0002-9939-1966-0200219-9/home.html) by M.A. Harrison.  It is derived by understanding the action of the symmetric group $S_n$ on $n\times n$ Cayley tables and using evaluations of cycle index polynomials to derive the formula. See also [this OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A001329) for other references and further values.

Comment: @marcotrevi The formula should be complicated, but the method should be fairly simple to explain: apply Burnside's lemma to the action of $S_n$.  Then we need to determine, for any permutation $\pi$, which magmas on $\{1,2,\ldots n\}$ are invariant under $\pi$.  This has some (not entirely trivial—double transitivity is involved) interpretation in terms of the cycle type of $\pi$.