# How many L-structures are there of size n with a single binary function symbol +?

Tags: logic

I am stuck on this question.

Let L be the language with a single binary function symbol + and let n be a positive integer. How many L-structures are there of size n?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you could use any set of size $n$ as the underlying set of the structure, so there's a proper class.  But presumably that's not what the question intends.  If you've copied the question exactly as it was written, then it is too ambiguous to answer.

Comment: It is exactly what question is. I think the binary function symbol + can be changed as any binary function.

Answer (score 1):

As Eric Wofsey pointed out in the comments, the way the question is stated is ambiguous. There are three possible ways to interpret the question:

- As written: How many $L$-structures are there of size $n$? Well, for any positive integer $n$, there are a proper class of sets of size $n$, and any set $X$ can be equipped with a binary operation $X^2\to X$, so there is a proper class of $L$-structures of size $n$.
- How many $L$-structures are there of size $n$ *up to isomorphism*? This is the question that Levi was addressing in the other answer. A formula for this is known, but it is quite complicated, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987217/number-of-different-magmas-up-to-isomorphism) (a *magma* is an $L$-structure in your language $L$, i.e. a set equipped with a binary operation).
- How many $L$-structures are there with domain $X$, where $X$ is a fixed set of size $n$ (e.g. $X = \{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$)? The answer is $n^{n^2}$, since the number of functions $X^2\to X$ is $|X|^{|X^2|}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** It is actually more complicated than what follows, see the comments of this answer.

**Original Answer:**
I believe that up to isomorphism, there are $n^{n^2}/n!$ possible $L$-structures, but I could be wrong. The idea is to note that there are $n^{n^2}$ binary operations you can define on a fixed set of $n$ elements (for any of the $n^2$ tuples you can choose one of the $n$ elements). But now there are some structures that you can obtain from others by renaming the elements. That's why we need to divide by the number of ways to rename the elements, which is $n!$.

Comment: Unfortunately it's more complicated than this: dividing by $n!$ would be the right thing to do if every binary function were counted $n!$ times up to isomorphism. But only the binary functions with no non-trivial automorphisms are counted $n!$ times. Those that have non-trivial automorphisms are counted fewer times. So a correct count needs to take into account the orbits of the action of $S_n$ on the set of multiplication tables - and this gets quite complicated!

Comment: You're totally right! Let me mark my answer accordingly.